# 'No tests found with testrunner JUnit4' when using JUnitParams

Tags: java, junit, junitparams

I have a test class which uses JUnitParams and when I try to run it, I get the error in the title. The JUnitParams library is correctly installed, and I don't have any compiler errors.
I am using JUnit 4.13 and JUnitParams 1.1.1 .

I am running the test from a custom run config, which is shown in the picture below. (I am running my project as a JUnit application, with JUnit4 as the test runner.)

[the setup for the project's run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNrJx.png)

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class GraphTest
{
@Test
@Parameters(method = "dijkstraParams")
@TestCaseName("{method}({params}) [{index}]") 
public void testDijkstra(int node1, int node2, int expectedDistance)
    throws GraphException
{
    int[][] input = new int[][] { 
            { 0, 1, 4 }, 
            { 0, 3, 2 }, 
            { 1, 2, 5 }, 
            { 1, 3, 1 }, 
            { 2, 3, 8 }, 
            { 2, 4, 1 }, 
            { 2, 5, 6 }, 
            { 3, 4, 9 }, 
            { 4, 5, 3 } 
    };

    int[][] inputGraph = addReverseConnections(input);

    Graph g = new Graph(input);

    int distance = g.dijkstra(node1, node2);

    assertThat(distance, is(expectedDistance));

    int[][] output = g.getConnections();

    assertThat(output, arrayContainingInAnyOrder(inputGraph));
}
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. 
Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, please be specific at to the nature of the error. If you are presented with a stack trace or error message, please include these in your post.

Comment: Also explain how you try to start the tests

Comment: I listened to your feedback and included everything you advised me to.

Comment: But where is the `dijkstraParams` method?